Does a form of address fall under the subject?
In the sentence "Tyler, you put away the dishes," I would infer that the subject is "you" and the predicate is "put away the dishes." So where does "Tyler" fit into this?
"Tyler, you" doesn't seem like a valid subject nor does "Tyler ... put away the dishes" seem like the correct predicate. If we instead said "You put away the dishes," which shouldn't change the meaning considering that we're talking to Tyler, the subject would still be "you" and the predicate still "put away the dishes."
Could "Tyler" be a form of address that's neither part of the subject nor predicate? Is it possible for sentences to contain more than just a subject and a predicate?

Per my comment under Lambie's answer, I'd say "Tyler" is a form of address that's neither part of the subject nor predicate.

You have accepted a wrong answer. Please read Difference vocative and appositive

"Tyler, you put away the dishes."
The pronoun you is an apposition to Tyler.
It's when you repeat the same idea right next to the original one.
Merriam Webster:

apposition noun
1 a
: a grammatical construction in which two or more usually adjacent
words, phrases, or clauses (especially nouns or noun equivalents) that
have the same referent stand in the same syntactical relation to the
rest of a sentence (such as the poet and Burns in "a biography of the
poet Burns")

Here, the appositional noun phrase Tyler, you is the subject.
OR
You could say Tyler is the subject and you its apposition.

OR you could say Tyler is just a "noun of direct address" /  "vocative noun". Same as "Mum, where are my clean socks?"

@FumbleFingers Yes, but it's not a good idea to build Rome in one day and the question was about subjects and predicates. Go ahead and put it in if you like.

I don't think the cited example is really the same as, for example, Tyler, you're an idiot!, which I would call a "true" apposition. The thing is my example could occur quite naturally in contexts where the only people around ate Tyler and the speaker. But OP's example would be bizarre if there were only the two of them. Obviously that initial vocative is only justified because it has the very specific dual functions of grabbing the addressee's attention and identifying who is being addressed (i.e. - there must be others present who are not being addressed).

@FumbleFingers Please don't be a pain. Either add it to my answer or let's leave it.

I. Vocative: word or phrase to address someone directly

Does a form of address fall under the subject?
In the sentence "Tyler, you put away the dishes," I would infer that the subject is "you" and the predicate is "put away the dishes." So where does "Tyler" fit into this?

"Tyler" acts as a  vocative— a word or phrase used to address someone directly. A vocative doesn’t play a grammatical role in the sentence's main structure, meaning it isn’t part of the subject, predicate, or any other core grammatical function.
Sentences can contain more than just a subject and predicate. Additional elements like vocatives, interjections, or parentheticals can add extra meaning or emphasis but remain separate from the main grammatical structure.
II. Explanation: The vocative case..

The vocative case is used to show direct address (i.e., to show when you are talking to somebody or something directly). In English, words in the vocative case are offset using commas.
.

Vocative Case

III. Difference vocative and appositive.

Appositive: In "Brasília, the capital of Brazil, is known for its modern architecture", "the capital of Brazil" is an appositive that clarifies which "Brasília" is being mentioned.
.
Vocative: In the sentence "John, come here!", "John" is the vocative, as it is the name of the person being called by the speaker.
Adnominal Complement, Adverbial Complement, Apposition, and Vocative

